# Resizing adjacent snapped windows in Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607

Before the Anniversary Update for Windows 10 that came out in early August 2016, I was able to resize adjacent snapped windows. Now that I have the Anniversary Update, that feature doesn't seem to work any longer. How can I restore this capability?

I have the "When I resize a snapped window, simultaneously resize any adjacent snapped window" feature enabled (see screenshot).

[image]